# PCA change colours of clusters

Tags: r, pca, factoextra

I want to change the colours of my clusters but maintain the shape.  `habillage=iris$Species` changes both colour and shape, what can to change only colours?

```
library("devtools")
install_github("kassambara/factoextra")
library("factoextra")
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)
fviz_pca_ind(iris.pca,  geom="point",  pointsize = 1, habillage=iris$Species, addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fviz_pca()` works like ggplot plots, hence, for changing shapes you can use the aesthetic mappings of ggplot, e.g., for changing shapes. Concerning colors, the documentation called by `?fviz_pca_ind` tells you that you can change colors via `palette`.

```
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,  geom="point",  pointsize = 1, habillage=iris$Species, addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95
             , palette = c("green", "orange", "grey") #change colors
             ) + 
             scale_shape_manual(values=c(2, 8, 11)) #change shapes
```

Comment: I am trying to use palette without `habillage=iris$Species` but it does not work, why do I need it?

Comment: I am not an expert with fviz, but from my understanding you need to tell the function at some point, by which factors you group your data. This is handled by habillage. If you do not use habillage `fviz`does not "know" that there are three groups, hence, you cannot use settings, such as palette, that require a certain number of groups (three in your example).